# Toggle between "Extend these displays" and "Show desktop only on 1"

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I'm looking for a way to programmatically alter the video properties in Windows 7.  I'd like to toggle the Multiple display state (as seen in Control Panel > Appearances and Personalization > Display > Screen Resolution) between "Extend these displays" and "Show desktop only on 1".

This is the sort of thing that I think is probably doable just by knowing the right Windows executable/dll to invoke with the right parameters and bundling that into a script or shortcut, but if so that information eludes me.

Actual code solutions are fine, of course, but I'd like the change to be permanent and not just disable the other monitor(s) for the duration of the application.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are still interested in the answer, the shortcut is win+p. You can use Autohotkey for scripting and call autohotkey script from your program. It is a workaround but better than nothing.

Comment: Amaaaaaazing.  How did I not know about this?  Note:  doesn't work in XP or Vista; just a Win7 feature.  Maybe that's why :)